# Error loading CuDNNLSTM with Tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Activation, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
```

and

```
        self.model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm1_size, input_shape=(
            seq_length, feature_dim), return_sequences=True))
        # self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm2_size, return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm3_size, return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm4_size, return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(Dense(feature_dim, activation='linear'))
```

But the error I get is:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.cudnn_recurrent.CuDNNLSTM object at 0x140869be0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing imports between the `keras` and `tf.keras` libraries, these are not the same library, and doing this is not supported.

You need to make all imports from one of the libraries:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed, Activation, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import Sequence
from keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
```

Comment: Then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'`

Comment: @Shamoon Are you using a version of Keras that supports TensorFlow 2.1? You can also use tf.keras, but as I said, you need to make all imports from it.

Comment: I’m using Keras 2.3.1

Answer (score 4):

If you are using tensorflow 2 you will need to include using the compat layer:

> from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

as CuDNNLSTM doesn't exist on keras.layer (v2)